# Showing that the limit of a function is $e^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I want to find the convergence radius of

$$ P(z) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{j-3}{j}\right)^{j^2}z^j$$
with $z$ being a complex number, with the use of

$$e^x = \lim_{j\to\infty} (1+x/j)^j$$

Using the root test, the convergence radius is

$$R =  \lim_{j\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[j]{\left\lvert \left(\frac{j-3}{j}\right)^{j^2} \right\rvert}}$$
I tried to rewrite the expression into a form simliar to $e^x$:

$$R = \lim_{j\to\infty} \sqrt[j]{\left\lvert \left(1+\frac{3}{j-3}\right)^{j^2} \right\rvert} $$

Now it looks like the convergence radius to be $e^3$ but I am not sure how to show this in a non-intuitive way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$\sqrt[j]{\left(\frac{j-3}j\right)^{j^2}}=\left(\frac{j-3}j\right)^j=\left(1-\frac3j\right)^j.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: This is a good answer, why the -1?

Comment: @JoshuaWang A bit of random noise, I think.

Comment: I think so. Because the expression you wrote is in the denominator of the convergence radius I write -j in the exponent, so that the limit of this expression  would then be  $$e^{-x}$$ and because we have x=-3 we have $$e^{-(-3)}$$ and therefore is the convergence radius $$R=e^3$$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you a lot! What is your argument for ignoring the absolute value of the expression under the root?

Comment: @JosefHuber If $j>1$, $\left(\frac{j-3}j\right)^j\geqslant0$.